# Checking if an user exists in an array of users

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to create a user login system with React and Redux. I use a mockup data as follows :

```
const users = [
{
    "id":1,
    "username":"user1",
    "email":"user@hotmail.com",
    "password":"1527393"
},
{
    "id":2,
    "username":"user2",
    "email":"user2@hotmail.com",
    "password":"1527393"
}
];


export default users;
```

This data is added to the store via default state. My store.js file is as follows :

```
    import {createStore, compose} from 'redux';
import rootReducer from '../reducers/index';

import userLoginReducer from '../data/users';

const defaultState = {
    userLoginReducer
};

export default function configureStore() {
    return createStore(
        rootReducer,
        defaultState,
        compose(
            window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f //we use this line for chrome redux extension
        )
    );
}
```

My login components which is connected to redux is :

```
    import React from 'react';
import LoginForm from './loginForm';

import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import * as actionCreators from '../../actions/actionCreators';

class Login extends React.Component {

    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);

        this.state = {
            loginData: {
                username: '',
                password: ''
            },
            errors: {}
        };

        this.buttonClickHandle = this.buttonClickHandle.bind(this);
        this.loginHandle = this.loginHandle.bind(this);
    }

    loginHandle(event) {
        let field = event.target.name;
        let value = event.target.value;

        let loginData = this.state.loginData;
        loginData[field] = value;

        this.setState({loginData: loginData});
    }

    buttonClickHandle(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.props.actions.userLoginSuccess(this.state.loginData.username, this.state.loginData.password);

        if (this.props.users.length > 0) {
            console.log("User exists. Go to the login page");
        } else {
            console.log("User doesn't exists. Show error message");
        }
    }

    render() {
        const language = this.props.currentLanguage;
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <p className="col-lg-4 col-xs-12 col-md-4 loginTitle noPadding">{language.loginTitle}</p>
                    <div className="col-lg-8 col-xs-12 col-md-8 loginForm noPadding">
                        <LoginForm currentLanguage={language} onClick={this.buttonClickHandle}
                                   onChange={this.loginHandle} errors={this.state.errors}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return {
        users: state.userLoginReducer
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch)
    };
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login);
```

On a page load I get those two users from data file. That's ok.

In the buttonClickHandle function in Login component I call an action with the username and password and I want to check if the returned array from the reducer is empty. If it is empty I would than update state.errors and if it's not empty I would that redirect to the welcome page.

In the reducer I filter the data and check if the user with the action.username exists and I return that array to my Login component.

The reducer code is as follows :

```
    export default function userLoginReducer(state = [], action) {
    switch(action.type){
        case "USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS":
            return [...state.filter(user => user.username === action.username)];
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work.

If I when the page loads submit the form with username user1 it works, but it works also when I submit it when page loads with for example user18.

Any advice?

Comment: >But it doesn't work. What do you mean? Any errors in the console?

Comment: It doesn't work like it should. There is no errors in the console. But the problem is _If I when the page loads submit the form with username user1 it works, but it works also when I submit it when page loads with for example user18._

Comment: Have you seen my answer?

Comment: `"On a page load I get those two users from data file."` Where?

Comment: In console. With `console.log(this.props.users)` I see that they are returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the code meant to check if the user exist is not right.

You have

```
if (this.props.users.length > 0) {
 console.log("User exists. Go to the login page");
} else {
 console.log("User doesn't exists. Show error message");
}
```

But, assuming your checking against your `users` object which contains two objects, `this.props.users.length > 0` will always return `true`. Even when you check for a user that is not in `users`.

You need to add a way of checking the actual username, with `indexOf` or `includes` or something. For instance, this would work:

```
const { users } = this.props;

if (users.length > 0 && users.find(user => user.username === this.state.loginData.username)) {
 console.log("User exists. Go to the login page");
} else {
 console.log("User doesn't exists. Show error message");
}
```

Comment: I should than always return all users with the reducer and then check when the button is clicked if `this.state.loginData.username` exists in the returned array from the reducer?